# Парсинг csv с помощью pandas

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-model

пытаюсь добавить данные из CSV файла в DB django

Исполняемый код:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import pandas as pd
from ...models import Suppliers, Articles


def get_products():
    tmp_data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Sirius_McLine/PycharmProjects/BrixoDoc/ImportCSV/articles.csv', sep=';')
    products = [
        Articles(
            ExternalId=tmp_data.loc[row]['ART_ID'],
            SupplierId=Suppliers.objects.get(id=tmp_data.loc[row]['SUP_NAME']),
            AssemblyGroup=tmp_data.loc[row]['Assembly_Group'],
            GenericArticle=tmp_data.loc[row]['Generic_Article'],
            ArticleNumber=tmp_data.loc[row]['ART_NUM'],
            Type=1,
            GenericArticleNumber=8,
        )
        for row in tmp_data
    ]
    Articles.objects.bulk_create(products)


def clear_data():
    """
    Очистить все записи в таблице Product
    """
    Articles.objects.all().delete()


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        clear_data()
        get_products()
        print("---------------------------------------PRODUCTS WAS ADDED----------------------------------------------")
```

Файл CSV:

```
ART_ID;ART_NUM;GEN_ART_NO;SUP_NAME;Assembly_Group;Generic_Article;ATTRIBUTES

4937#FL1105;FL1105;1537;FIT;Тормозная система;Комплект тормозных башмаков, барабанные тормоза;[]
4937#FL1106;FL1106;1537;FIT;Тормозная система;Комплект тормозных башмаков, барабанные тормоза;[]
4937#FL1110;FL1110;1537;FIT;Тормозная система;Комплект тормозных башмаков, барабанные тормоза;[]
4937#FL1111;FL1111;1537;FIT;Тормозная система;Комплект тормозных башмаков, барабанные тормоза;[]
4937#FL1112;FL1112;1537;FIT;Тормозная система;Комплект тормозных башмаков, барабанные тормоза;[]
4937#FL1114;FL1114;1537;FIT;Тормозная система;Комплект тормозных башмаков, барабанные тормоза;[]
```

На выходе получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\SiteBrixo\management\commands\imortCSV.py", line 33, in handle
    get_products()
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\SiteBrixo\management\commands\imortCSV.py", line 8, in get_products
    products = [
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\SiteBrixo\management\commands\imortCSV.py", line 10, in <listcomp>
    ExternalId=tmp_data.loc[row]['ART_ID'],
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 967, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1202, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1153, in _get_label
    return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3864, in xs
    loc = index.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 389, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'ART_ID'
```

В чем может быть проблема?
Я пробовал указывать явно столбец     `for row in tmp_data['name']`
Но ошибка та же самая.

```html
def get_products():
    tmp_data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Sirius_McLine/PycharmProjects/BrixoDoc/ImportCSV/articles.csv', sep=';')
    products = [
        Articles(
            ExternalId=tmp_data[row]['ART_ID'],
            SupplierId=Suppliers.objects.get(id=tmp_data[row]['SUP_NAME']),
            AssemblyGroup=tmp_data[row]['Assembly_Group'],
            GenericArticle=tmp_data[row]['Generic_Article'],
            ArticleNumber=tmp_data[row]['ART_NUM']
        )
        for row in tmp_data.index
    ]
    Articles.objects.bulk_create(products)
```

Новая ошибка:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3621, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\SiteBrixo\management\commands\imortCSV.py", line 10, in <listcomp>
    ExternalId=tmp_data[row]['ART_ID'],
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3505, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
```

Новая ошибка:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1988, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'FIT'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\SiteBrixo\management\commands\imortCSV.py", line 33, in handle
    get_products()
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\SiteBrixo\management\commands\imortCSV.py", line 8, in get_products
    products = [
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\SiteBrixo\management\commands\imortCSV.py", line 11, in <listcomp>
    SupplierId=Suppliers.objects.get(id=tmp_data.loc[row]['SUP_NAME']),
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 482, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1071, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1089, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1096, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1466, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1496, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1412, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1242, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 85, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\Sirius_McLine\PycharmProjects\BrixoDoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1990, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'FIT'.
```

Новый код с .loc

```html
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import pandas as pd
from ...models import Suppliers, Articles


def get_products():
    tmp_data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Sirius_McLine/PycharmProjects/BrixoDoc/ImportCSV/articles.csv', sep=';')
    products = [
        Articles(
            ExternalId=tmp_data.loc[row]['ART_ID'],
            SupplierId=Suppliers.objects.get(id=tmp_data.loc[row]['SUP_NAME']),
            AssemblyGroup=tmp_data.loc[row]['Assembly_Group'],
            GenericArticle=tmp_data.loc[row]['Generic_Article'],
            ArticleNumber=tmp_data.loc[row]['ART_NUM'],
            Type=1,
            GenericArticleNumber=8,
        )
        for row in tmp_data.index
    ]
    Articles.objects.bulk_create(products)


def clear_data():
    """
    Очистить все записи в таблице Product
    """
    Articles.objects.all().delete()


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        clear_data()
        get_products()
        print("---------------------------------------PRODUCTS WAS ADDED----------------------------------------------")
```

Comment: Попробуйте параметр `index_col=False` для `pd.read_csv`, у вас наверняка эта первая колонка попала в индекс, а не в обычные колонки.

Comment: Кажется, тут будет актуален `skip_blank_lines=True` в `read_csv`

Comment: Для контроля напечатайте список колонок `print(tmp_data.columns)`

Comment: `index_col=False` добавил, безрезультатно. Что мне даст    `print(tmp_data.columns)`  Ну увидел я колонки    `Index(['ART_ID', 'ART_NUM', 'GEN_ART_NO', 'SUP_NAME', 'Assembly_Group',
       'Generic_Article', 'ATTRIBUTES'],
      dtype='object')` не понимаю как это мне поможет? )

Comment: `skip_blank_lines=True` добавил, не помогло

Comment: А, я понял. Вы посмотрите, что у вас в `row`. Там как-раз названия колонок перебираются, а не строки. Если хотите, чтобы заработала ваша конструкция без сильных изменений, перебирайте `row` так: `for row in df.index:`

Comment: ТО есть в моем случае это    `for row in tmp_data.index` ? Не помогло((  все же лезет ошибка    `\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
`

Comment: Странно, `loc` работает именно по индексу, теперь то должно работать :/

Comment: Ниже добавил в вопросе, так как вы предложили. Может я все таки что то не то делаю?))

Comment: Код вроде правильный, добавьте внизу ещё ошибку, которая выходит с этим кодом

Comment: Добавил ниже новую ошибку.

Comment: А почему вы `.loc` убрали везде?! `df[key]` - это доступ к **колонке**, а `df.loc[key]` - это доступ к **строке** даных! Верните `.loc`!! В первом варианте кода он был, а во втором исчез. И я ведь удивлялся в комментарии, что `.loc` не работает, вы могли бы уже тогда догадаться, что чего-то не хватает :)

Comment: Да, тупанул)). Но все же появилась новая ошибка(( Еще ниже прикрепил как сейчас

Comment: Я так понимаю тут ругается `id=tmp_data.loc[row]['SUP_NAME']`, у вас там не `id` видимо в `SUP_NAME`, а вы ищете как по `id`, который должен быть числом.

Comment: Верно, закоментил эту строчку, все заработало и база наполнилась) А по поводу то строчки это уже другой вопрос, спасибо большое вам)))